# ¿Cómo mostrar varias imagenes con Animación CSS en React?

Tags: css, reactjs, animacion-css

Hola estoy aprendiendo animación con CSS estoy usando **MakeStyles** en React pero no me permite hacer animaciones. Lo que quiero hacer es que mi componente (el div) muestre diversas imágenes como si fueran diapositivas. Todo va bien en mi selector **images** pero no entra al keyframes, por lo tanto no me proyecta ninguna imagen, no sé si lo estoy haciendo mal esto es lo que tengo:

```
   import React from 'react';
   import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
   import Imagen1 from '/img1.jpg';
   import Imagen2 from '/img2.jpg';
   import Imagen3 from '/img3.jpg';

   const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
      images:{
        width: 500,
        height: 300,
        animationName: "slide",
        animationDuration: "10s",
        animationIterationCount: "infinite",
        animationDelay: "3s",
      },
      "@-webkit-keyframes slide": {
        "0%":{
          backgroundImage: `url(${Imagen1})`,
        },
        "50%":{
          backgroundImage: `url(${Imagen2})`,
        },
        "100%":{
          backgroundImage: `url(${Imagen3})`,
        }
    }));

    export default function Component(){
      const classes = useStyles();
    
      return(
        <div className={classes.images}>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

A lo mejor existe una mejor forma de resolverlo, cualquier comentario o aportación lo agradezco :)

Comment: Prueba usando `animationName: "$slide"` en vez de `animationName: "slide"`

Comment: @FranAcuna ya lo acabo de intentar y no resulta bro